# Python Flask Restful API Query

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

I am new to REST and was wondering if this is right?

```
@app.route('/addticket/<name>')
def addticket(name):
    tick = Tickets(event_name=name, redeemed=False)
    try:
        db.session.add(tick)
        db.session.commit()
    except:
        return 'There was an issue adding a ticket'
    viewer = Tickets.query.filter(Tickets.event_name==name).all()
    
    return render_template('view.html', viewer = viewer, title = name )
```

I am required to create a service (backend) application that exposes the RESTful
endpoints to accomplish the task.

In this method, I am adding an additional ticket to an event.

Just confused if I have to return JSON serialised.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a seperate endpoint to fetch data and parse it to json instead of using the same endpoint to put and fetch data.

```
@app.route('/getticket/<name>',methods=['GET'])
def getticket(name):

viewer = Tickets.query.filter(Tickets.event_name==name).all()
jsonify({'response': viewer })
```